# Sql raw query doesn't works properly

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using an except clause on my query, But however I get an error as below:

The text format of the query is :

```
select songs.id, songs.name, songs.artist, songs.album, songs.albumart, songs."albumartThumbnail", cpr.votes, is_requested from (select id, name, artist, album, albumart, "albumartThumbnail" from (select song_id from core_plsongassociation where playlist_id in (1477)) as sinpl
                        left join songs on sinpl.song_id=id where explicit=False
                    ) as songs left join
                    (select song_id, votes, bool_or(thirdpartyuser_id=177) as is_requested from
                        (select * from core_priorityrequests where client_id=2876 and is_played=False
                        ) as clpr left join core_priorityrequests_third_party_user on clpr.id=priorityrequests_id
                        group by priorityrequests_id, song_id, votes
                ) as cpr on songs.id=cpr.song_id 
                EXCEPT
                (select core_blockedsongs_song.song_id from core_blockedsongs 
                join core_blockedsongs_song on core_blockedsongs.id=core_blockedsongs_song.blockedsongs_id where core_blockedsongs.unblock_flag = 'f' and core_blockedsongs.client_id=2870);
```

The reason for above error is due to the difference in the columns in the queries which are **below** and **above** the **except** clause, i.e. The columns in the query that is written above the except has more columns than the query after the except clause which has just 1(one) column.

Can anyone suggest any workaround/solution as an improvement in the query which is written in except so that I don't have to add all the columns in it?

**Update 1**:

I have my model updated as below, Now the Song field is a foreign key and earlier it was many-to-many field.

```
  class BlockSong(models.Model):
      client = models.ForeignKey('Client')
      user= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)      
      playlist = models.ForeignKey('Playlist', blank=True, null=True)
      song = models.ForeignKey('Song')
      unblock_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The issue with the answer is that now the query given in the below answer gives an error.

```
select core_blockedsongs_song.song_id 
  from core_blockedsongs join core_blockedsongs_song 
  on core_blockedsongs.id=core_blockedsongs_song.blockedsongs_id
```

Could you please suggest what changes in the query needs to be done when a field is updated from many-to-many field to foreign key. Here, the Song field has been updated.

Comment: You can use `null` for each of the missing columns, which will remove the error message but I don't think this will return what you want. Post the code in text format and not an image so it is readable.

Comment: @forpas added the text format.

Comment: @forpas using null produces the results... but the result is incorrect. Could you please help by something else?

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add dummy `null` columns in the 2nd query so EXCEPT will allow the statement to be executed, like:

```
EXCEPT
      (select core_blockedsongs_song.song_id, null, null,.... from core_blockedsongs
```

but I think that this is not what you want, because:

> EXCEPT returns all rows that are in the result of query1 but not in
>   the result of query2

which means that full rows are compared.
What I undestand is that you want to exclude from the results of the 1st query all the `song_id`s returned by the 2nd query.
If this is the case then you can use instead `NOT IN` like this:

```
select songs.id, songs.name, songs.artist, songs.album, songs.albumart, songs."albumartThumbnail", 
       cpr.votes, is_requested 
from (
  select id, name, artist, album, albumart, "albumartThumbnail" 
  from (
    select song_id 
    from core_plsongassociation 
    where playlist_id in (1477)
    ) as sinpl left join songs 
    on sinpl.song_id=id 
    where explicit=False
  ) as songs left join (
    select song_id, votes, bool_or(thirdpartyuser_id=177) as is_requested 
    from (
      select * 
      from core_priorityrequests 
      where client_id=2876 and is_played=False
    ) as clpr left join core_priorityrequests_third_party_user 
    on clpr.id=priorityrequests_id
    group by priorityrequests_id, song_id, votes
) as cpr on songs.id=cpr.song_id 
where songs.id not in (
  select core_blockedsongs_song.song_id 
  from core_blockedsongs join core_blockedsongs_song 
  on core_blockedsongs.id=core_blockedsongs_song.blockedsongs_id 
  where core_blockedsongs.unblock_flag = 'f' and core_blockedsongs.client_id=2870
);
```

Or with a `LEFT JOIN` of the 2nd query from which you will filter out the matching rows:

```
select songs.id, songs.name, songs.artist, songs.album, songs.albumart, songs."albumartThumbnail", 
       cpr.votes, is_requested 
from (
  select id, name, artist, album, albumart, "albumartThumbnail" 
  from (
    select song_id 
    from core_plsongassociation 
    where playlist_id in (1477)
    ) as sinpl left join songs 
    on sinpl.song_id=id 
    where explicit=False
  ) as songs left join (
    select song_id, votes, bool_or(thirdpartyuser_id=177) as is_requested 
    from (
      select * 
      from core_priorityrequests 
      where client_id=2876 and is_played=False
    ) as clpr left join core_priorityrequests_third_party_user 
    on clpr.id=priorityrequests_id
    group by priorityrequests_id, song_id, votes
) as cpr on songs.id=cpr.song_id 
left join (
  select core_blockedsongs_song.song_id 
  from core_blockedsongs join core_blockedsongs_song 
  on core_blockedsongs.id=core_blockedsongs_song.blockedsongs_id 
  where core_blockedsongs.unblock_flag = 'f' and core_blockedsongs.client_id=2870
) as c on c.song_id = songs.id
where c.song_id is null;
```

Comment: Works @forpas . However, out of curiosity, which of the above two is recommended. I mean tried both of them. And both of them absolutely fine.

Comment: I rarely use queries with `not in` because if there is a case that in the list there may be `null`s then the results are not correct. In your case I suppose there are no `null`s because a column like `song_id` can't be `null` in the table `core_blockedsongs_song` (I'm guessing by the name of the table that this column must always have a value). So if there is no performance problem I would use the join.

Comment: unfortunately due to some rephrasing my song field in blocksong has been changed to a foreign key from many-to-many field. Can you please help me with the changes that needs to be done?

Comment: I can't tell by what you mention how this changes the relations of the tables. Post a new question where you explain the design of the tables and their relations and what is the requirement.

Comment: I have added an update 1 for more clarity. could you now please check?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62171135/postgres-raw-query-for-foreign-key-in-django Added a new question @forpas

Comment: can you please help now.

Comment: Hi @forpas , I have a constraint  '(where songs.name ilike %s or songs.artist ilike %s limit %s offset %s)' but however when I am using it, it returns in error. Could you atleast please suggest/help.